# Problemas com relacionamento de tabelas no laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, relacionamento

Quando eu digito `php artisan migrate` ele gera esse erro:

```
  Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 
  Can't create table `blog`.`produtos` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint 
  is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `produtos` add constraint 
  `produtos_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` 
  (`id`) on delete cascade)


  Exception trace:

 PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 
 `blog`.`produtos` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly
```

Veja como está o meu código

```
Schema::create('produtos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->string('nome');
        $table->integer('quantidade');
        $table->integer('valor');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Onde devo estar errando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O formato de dado da chave estrangeira deve ser igual do valor externo (chave primária) que etá fazendo relação.

É comum a chave primária da tabela de usuários (blog.users.id) ser criada com o método **bigIncrements**. Dessa forma, a sua coluna `user_id` da tabela produtos deve ser criada com o método **unsignedBigInteger**.

Dessa forma, ambas as colunas que está relacionando serão do formato `biginteger(20) unsigned`